# Use machine hostname inside VSCode launch.json file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'd like to know if it's possible to have the `launch.json` file of VSCode using the `hostname` of my machine. To be more precisely, I'd like to use the hostname in the `configurations.url` properties, something like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch",
            "url": "https://<<hostname>>/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the `url` properties has `<<hostname>>`; though, I'd like that, when pressing `F5`, that `<<hostname>>` is automatically replaced with the machine hostname (e.g. `DESKTOP-JUWKA3`).

I've tried to look for answer on stackOverflow, as well as VSCode official site:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

I thought something was possible with the information in the second link, but unfortunately I haven't been able to do that (maybe I'm not capable of doing it >_>)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the environment variable for host name:

```
"url": "https://${env:hostname}/",
```

Comment: It's a very old question, so the context in which I was using that launch.json is long gone :) But I will try your solution, it might have so much potential!